# Can I define powerpoints or presentations in raw text?

Tags: latex, powerpoint

Hi Guys : I wanted to create a power point presentation using a raw text file, so that i can rapidly edit the file and see the results, gauranteed with uniform formatting.  Basically, I'm talking about separating the data content from the presentation.

How can I do this ?  Im thinking that maybe Latex could be a choice.  I've also seen that there are API's for Powerpoint and open office presentations.

Comment: Do you want "powerpoint" or any kind of presentation format?

Comment: No TeX implementation I know of can output PPT format (and why on Earth would it want to, PDF is way better in comparison).

Comment: Your question is not really on-topic here (not about Software development), and also not constructive the way you asked. If you want to create a presentation (not a PowerPoint document) with LaTeX, have a look at the `beamer` class (and if you hit problems, ask on [TeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: @Paŭlo I disagree - this is on topic because the OP is asking about a programattic method of transforming data (text) to another format (LaTeX / .ppt), which is most definitely a task of interest to programmers

Comment: @arnaud Any type of presentation is fine. (pdf sounds good)

Comment: @AndrewWalker: Ah, I didn't read the question carefully enough to see it is searching a way to write a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerpoint exposes it's API via COM - which makes it possible to do (almost) anything that you can do in the GUI in any programming language that supports COM. The difficulty is that the API changes between releases. One way to scope out the API is to use the macro recording facility to manually do one slide, and then translate that to your target language.

I've got some old (not tested recently) python code for Powerpoint 2003 that should give you an idea of what the code might look like depending on your layout needs.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

ppLayoutTitle = 1
ppLayoutText  = 2

def writePresentation( fname, data ):
    pptApp = Dispatch('Powerpoint.Application')
    pres   = pptApp.ActivePresentation
    aw     = pptApp.ActiveWindow
    slides = pres.Slides

    for item in data:
        t1 = item[0]
        t2 = item[1]
        stype = item[2]
        assert(stype in [ppLayoutTitle,ppLayoutText])
        s = slides.Add( slides.Count, stype )
        aw.View.GotoSlide(s.SlideIndex)

        s.Shapes.Item(1).Select()
        aw.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select()
        aw.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start=1, Length=0).Select
        tr = aw.Selection.TextRange
        tr.Text = t1

        s.Shapes.Item(2).Select()
        aw.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select()
        if stype == ppLayoutText:
            aw.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Visible = 0
        aw.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start=1, Length=0).Select
        tr = aw.Selection.TextRange
        tr.Text = t2
    slides.Range(slides.Count).Delete()
    pres.SaveAs(fname)
```

**Edit:**

Openoffice (that can export to powerpoint) also ships with it's [scripting API](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) that could be used to solve similar problems.

Comment: So how do I get COM and python to interoperate on *NIX ?  Seems like there are some windows specific libraries.

Comment: I don't know if that snippet will work off windows. I haven't tried it, but it might under Wine. Have edited the answer to provide an alternative *NIX compatible solution.

Comment: Because the example code automates PowerPoint, at a minimum, you'd need a copy of PowerPoint installed and functional.  Other than Windows ... or a suitable emulator ... it won't work.  As to PPT version differences, I don't see anything in the code that would be affected; the same code should work identically on any version of PPT from '97 onward.  Generally, though, there's no reason to use Select on anything here, and doing so will slow the code substantially and prevent you from running PPT invisibly.  FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is slides with titles and bulleted text, it's quite simple. Create a txt file that looks like this (use the TAB key in place of  below):

```
Slide 1 Title
<tab>Bullet Level One Text
<tab><tab>Bullet Level Two Text
<tab>Back to Bullet Leven One again
Slide 2 Title
Slide 3 Title
<tab>More Bulleted text
<tab><tab>Tufte hates us by now
<tab><tab>But we don't care, do we?
Slide 4 Title
```

And so on.  Save the file, start PowerPoint, choose the file open command, choose Outline or files of all types in the file open dialog box and select your TXT file.  Done.